# How to make Entity Framework Add-Migration case sensitive

Tags: entity-framework

I changed an entity property from name to Name and the Add-Migration command didn't add the change to the migration file. Is it possible to set the command to pick up on changes with case sensitivity? Or do I have to drop the columns and add them again?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the column from "testname" to something like "testnames". Add migration
Rename column back to "TestName". Add migration
Alternatively, you can manually edit generated migration code